# strange beahviour with a php switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

A sample of what I'm trying to do will be more explicit:

```
   var_dump($opti_point); //int 0

    if ($opti_point>=0 && $opti_point < 25) echo 'good';//echoing good

    switch ($opti_point) {

        case ($opti_point>= 0 && $opti_point < 25):
            $test = 0;
            break;

        case ($opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50):
            echo 'we are in this case'; // This case is called !
            $test = 2;
            break;

        default:
            test = 0;
            break;
    }
```

Is there a trick here ?

thx

Comment: You can't put computation in the CASE statement.

Comment: @Fabrizio D., you can. Why not? `case 5+5: $result = 10;`

Comment: @Nemoden You're right, you can, but I meant to discourage adding logic in CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing what you think you are comparing. This is the code I think you want.

```
var_dump($opti_point); //int 0

if ($opti_point>=0 && $opti_point < 25) {
    $test = 0;
    echo 'You are now here!';
} elseif ($opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50) {
    $test = 2;
} else {
    test = 0;
}
```

In your example, you are comparing the result of the logical statement...

```
($opti_point>=0 && $opti_point < 25) // true
```

To the value of $opti_point

```
0 // false
```

So PHP is actually converting what you think in an integer into a boolean to compare it with the result of the conditional statement.

Comment: Thx for all the answers I learn something today ! I will go with this solution (first thing I ve done though but i judge it to verbose and try the switch one!)...Thx

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put comparisons inside "case" unfortunately...
A switch is only used when a value can have one of a limited number of values like so:

```
switch ( $val ) {
  case 1:
    echo "Got 1";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "Got 2";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Got invalid value";
}
```

A workaround would be to use:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($opti_point>= 0 && $opti_point < 25):
        $test = 0;
        break;

    case ($opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50):
        echo 'we are in this case';
        $test = 2;
        break;

    default:
        test = 0;
        break;
}
```

Which will work, but is a bit ugly...

Also, you're missing a single quote in `echo we are in this case';` which should be `echo 'we are in this case';`

You should be using an if instead =)

Comment: I dont htink its ugly if there are a ton of conditions. In this case for only 3 though i have to agree if/else is probably cleaner. But id use the switch if was +=4 conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `switch` argument to `true` of `false` if you do comparison liek that in the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a very bad way to use a switch statement, you should not put conditional sentences in the cases... In fact, I'm sure that that would be illegal in other languages and I'm not sure that it should work in PHP. Use a number of concatenated if-else conditions instead:

```
if ($i == 0) {
    echo "i equals 0";
} elseif ($i == 1) {
    echo "i equals 1";
} elseif ($i == 2) {
    echo "i equals 2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding on how `switch-case` works. `Case` DOES NOT TEST YOUR EXPRESSION TO BE boolean TRUE!

**It compares its value to 'switch' value!**

Here is an explanation:

`$opti_point>= 0 && $opti_point < 25` evalutes to true which integer representation is 1 and since `PHP` can deal with types on it's own, it turnes true to 1 and compares it with value in switch which is 0

`$opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50` evaluates to false which is 0 as integer, so...  that's your case ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go true the code with you

```
   var_dump($opti_point); //int 0 , or false  --- you should use TRUE

    if ($opti_point>=0 && $opti_point < 25) echo 'good';//echoing good

    switch ($opti_point) { // chose the case that is $opti_point (0 or false)

        case ($opti_point>= 0 && $opti_point < 25): // true, so go to next
            $test = 0;
            break;

        case ($opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50): //false si this is the wan I pick
            echo 'we are in this case'; // This case is called !
            $test = 2;
            break; // ingore the rest

        default:
            test = 0;
            break;
    }
```

you should use TRUE in the switch

Answer (score 1):

if this is the exact code then try this

var_dump($opti_point); //int 0

```
if ($opti_point>=0 && $opti_point < 25) echo 'good';//echoing good

switch ($opti_point) {

    case ($opti_point>= 0 && $opti_point < 25):
        $test = 0;
        break;

    case ($opti_point >= 25 && $opti_point < 50):
        echo 'we are in this case'; // This case is called !
        $test = 2;
        break;

    default:
        $test = 0;
        break;
}
```